# Git: run script on server when user connects to git

Tags: git

I would like to run a script on server side every time a user runs a git pull. However no hooks can achieve that, so I'm trying to find "hacks" to do so. Actually, I would also be happy to run the script "more often", for example every time a user connects through ssh.

I also want to do that as a non-root user (so I can't create new users), and I don't want to lose my hability to connect through regular ssh.

I tried to modify the bashrc file, but unfortunately the git protocol that uses ssh does not call this file. Any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to modify the bashrc file, but unfortunately the git protocol that uses ssh does not call this file. Any other idea?

Replace (or ask an admin to replace) on the server side the `/usr/bin/git-upload-pack` executable by a script which would:

- call the actual [`git upload-pack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-pack) command
- notifies you when it is called, since this is triggered by a fetch/pull

Comment: Thanks for the trick. This have however one drawbacks: it requires an admin access. Also, is it possible to get from the script the path of the git repository? It could be helpful to do the notification, by calling a specific file into this repo instead of sending notification to ull users.

Comment: @tobiasBora "it requires an admin access", that is why I mentioned asking to an admin. And the script should get as parameter the path of the repo (to be tested though)